# Send message from google api with the snippet

Tags: node.js, google-api, nightwatch.js

I am trying to send message via gmail api in the test, and then i want to find this message by his "snippet" in the receiving gmail-box. The request:

```
 sentMailRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',
        body: {
            raw: rawMailString,
            snippet: messageSnippet
        },
    };
```

then it request handles by the "request" method of 'google-auth-library'. This message send successfully but in received gmail account a seen message snippet = ''. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "snippet" - is an auto generated field, it's composed by the body of the message. Solution for me is in an adding to raw field the text of the message body:

```
mailString = 'From: 1@gmail.com\n' +
'To: 2@gmail.com\n' +
'Subject: test message send from google api\n' +
'\n' +
'body of the test message = snippet';
```

and then convert it to base 64 in the request:

```
sentMailRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',
        body: {
            raw: Buffer.from(mailString).toString('base64')
        },
    };
```

the snippet in this example will equal 'body of the test message = snippet'